# pickling an OrderedDict-derived object

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I built a subclass of collections.OrderedDict standard class. When I try to unpickle an object of this class I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pickle.py", line 29, in <module>
    print cPickle.load(f)
TypeError: ('__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)', <class '__main__.ConfiguratorsDict'>, ([['toto', 20]],))
```

Trying to understand the reason for such behaviour I narrowed the body of collections.OrderedDict to get the following minimal code that triggers the aformentionned error. Here it is:

```
import cPickle

class OrderedDict(dict):
    def __reduce__(self):
        items = [[k, self[k]] for k in self]
        inst_dict = vars(self).copy()
        for k in vars(OrderedDict()):
            inst_dict.pop(k, None)
        if inst_dict:
            return (self.__class__, (items,), inst_dict)

        return self.__class__, (items,)

class ConfiguratorsDict(OrderedDict):

    def __init__(self):
        OrderedDict.__init__(self)

        self._myspec = "blabla"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    f = open("test.pickle","wb")
    c = ConfiguratorsDict()
    c["toto"] = 20
    cPickle.dump(c,f)
    f.close()    
    f = open("test.pickle","rb")
    print cPickle.load(f)
    f.close()
```

At this point, I really do not understand what is going wrong in there. Is there something I misunderstood with pickle mechanism or is there some trouble related to OrderedDict ?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3):

You didn't read the documentation for [`__reduce__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) carefully enough:

> When a tuple is returned, it must be between two and five elements
>   long. Optional elements can either be omitted, or `None` can be provided
>   as their value. The contents of this tuple are pickled as normal and
>   used to reconstruct the object at unpickling time. The semantics of
>   each element are:
>
> - A callable object that will be called to create the initial version of the object. **The next element of the tuple will provide
>     arguments for this callable**, and later elements provide additional
>     state information that will subsequently be used to fully reconstruct
>     the pickled data.

You are returning the class as callable and as second element the `items` hence the unpickle is trying to pass the `items` to the class thus calling `__init__`, but your `__init__` doesn't take any argument and hence you get an error.

You have to either change the `__init__` to accept the argument or avoid putting that as second element and you an empty tuple instead.

Comment: thanks a lot ! To be sincere, I read this section several times but without really understanding it. With your answer it is now definitely clearer.